# How do I build AlphaTab?

Tags: javascript, c#, visual-studio, open-source, haxe

I am trying to build + make changes to [AlphaTab](https://github.com/CoderLine/alphaTab), a tablature reader that can be displayed on the web using SVG. It is a Visual Studio solution, but I cannot figure out how to build it successfully (I also have little experience with VS). I am using Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise, which I have access to as a student.

There are multiple projects within the solution, but the build I want is the JavaScript file. I know that it first compiles to Haxe and then to JavaScript, first using [Phase](https://github.com/CoderLine/Phase), a C# -> Haxe compiler, which was also written by the AlphaTab creator.

Unfortunately this is all the info I have.. there aren't build instructions on the repo and I tried to reach out on his Contact page. I really like the look + simplicity of using AlphaTab and want to add some changes, but also if there are other open source tab editors (display on browser) that look as nice, please link if possible!

Answer (score 0):

There is an unmaintained haxe version of alphatab on the haxe branch of the main repo, did you try experimenting with that?
https://github.com/CoderLine/alphaTab/tree/Haxe
open the .hxproj file in HaxeDevelop
https://haxedevelop.org/
Or in Visual Studio Code
https://github.com/vshaxe/vshaxe
To see if it has enough features try the html in the bin folder.

Comment: Thanks for the info.. I will try this weekend and update